# transforming a SQL query to dynamic query with joins or subquery

Tags: hibernate, liferay, dynamicquery, dynamic-queries

I've a SQL query (2 variants) and I need to use it with dynamic queries.

In SQL it looks so (Variant 1 // via subquery):

```
SELECT AssetEntry.entryId , (
              SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM `MBMessage`
              WHERE classPK = AssetEntry.classPK
            ) AS comments
            FROM `AssetEntry`
            ORDER BY comments DESC
```

Or the alternative query with join and group:

```
SELECT AssetEntry.entryId, count(MBMessage.classPK)
 FROM `AssetEntry`
 JOIN MBMessage ON (AssetEntry.classPK = MBMessage.classPK)
 GROUP BY MBMessage.classPK
```

Both SQL Queries displays exactly the same!

Now I need to use one of them as dynamic query. I have no idea how to do a join and I have no idea how to do a subquery in the projection?!

Can anybody help me? THX

---

I had to do this with custom-sql.

Comment: Do you have solved it? I have similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a really specific case, which requires an aggregate-function in the `SELECT` statement.

I would suggest using [Custom query](http://www.liferay.com/en/community/wiki/-/wiki/1071674/Custom+queries+in+Liferay+5.2) (also known as [`custom-sql`](http://arunkumarsrm.blogspot.in/2011/01/custom-sql-in-liferay-plugin-portlet.html) in liferay) with finders in your case, instead of a `DynamicQuery`.

DynamicQuery API has limitations and will not work in your case (*speaking from experience, so if somebody else has other opinions or facts regarding the below points I would be more than happy to know*):

1. Joins are not possible with DynamicQuery.
2. Its possible to return a `count` or to return an individual columns value using `Projection` but not possible to return a column and count to-gather using projections.
3. Can use sub-query with DynamicQuery using projections but I don't think you can use a sub-query in the `select` statement with DynamicQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You have another way of doing this, With AssetEntryQuery.

```
AssetEntryQuery aeq = new AssetEntryQuery();
aeq.setClassName(MBMessage.class.getName());
aeq.set.... (Add any other criterions if you want to)
List<AssetEntry> assetEntries = AssetEntryServiceUtil.getEntries(aeq);
```